# How to sort data as in Excel?

Tags: sorting

How to create a program in Mathematica to sort data (table with several variables) by different variable, by clicking the name of the variable, much like in Excel with freeze pane?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: The last answer in the linked questions has a code updated that contains pretty much all the functionality expected from Excel in "How can I add column re-arangement ...". The code of the base function contains sorting that matches precisely multi-column sorting as in Excel. Might be what you are looking for out of the box.